# Why -fpermissive is triggered in my code

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I am trying to build a non-cyclic tree structure, with each node identified by a string, and with each branch node of type PrimMap.  All nodes on the same generation is saved as Item objects in a map.  Here is the abbreviated code:

```
class PrimMap {
    struct Item {  // a tagged union of different typed objects
        Item( PrimMap * pPrimMap );
        ...
    }
    PrimMap const * _pParent;  // point to fixed parent
    PrimMap( const std::string & contextName, PrimMap const * pParent );
    enum Error { ... };
    Error add( const std::string & key, Item item );
        // add an Item to a branch node
}

inline PrimMap::PrimMap( const std::string & contextName, PrimMap const * pParent ) : _pParent( pParent )
{
    if (pParent)
    {
        pParent->add( contextName, Item( this ) );
    }
}
```

The error message is:
    ../src/PrimMap.h:314:57: error: passing 'const PrimMap' as 'this' argument of 'PrimMap::Error PrimMap::add(const string&, PrimMap::Item)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   pParent->add( contextName, Item( this, fix, marker ) );

I fail to see how this error message makes sense--particularly, I could not see how "this" is associated with "const PrimMap" * in constructor.

What do I missed?

Comment: Please post more code (un-abbreviated). The error seems to be where you call the `Error` member function (which by its declaration could be expected to modify its object), probably on an object which is `const`, but I don't see that part of the code.  (What's on line 314?).  If you can strip down your code to something which compiles yet still exhibits the error, that would be ideal.

Comment: Error is a enum.  That is not the reason.  I will modify the original post to include more information.

Comment: The error message suggests that `pParent` points to a const object. In your code it points to a non-const object. Are you sure your "abbreviated" code is accurate? The `add` call in the error message looks different from what you posted in the code.

Comment: You are actually right. I should have used "PrimMap * const pParent" to fix the pointer pointing to. "PrimMap const * pParent" is identical to "const PrimMap * pParent" in gcc.

Answer (score 1):

> Why `-fpermissive` is triggered in my code

You are calling a non-`const` member function on a `const` object.

**Fix**

Since the parent object is going to be modified, remove the `const` in the argument of the function.

```
PrimMap( const std::string & contextName, PrimMap* pParent );
```

Change the implementation accordingly.

```
inline PrimMap::PrimMap( const std::string & contextName, PrimMap* pParent )
{
    if (pParent)
    {
        pParent->add( contextName, Item( this ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: The const is on the pointer, not on the object which the pointer points to.  That should not be the reason.

Comment: You are actually right. I should have used "PrimMap * const pParent" to fix the pointer pointing to.   "PrimMap const * pParent" is identical to "const PrimMap * pParent" in gcc.